# Install Magento2 Sniffer PSR 2

Tags: magento2

Where I have to upload a file phpcs.xml to install marketplace-eqp from https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/tree/master/MEQP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpcs xml file should be uploaded at the Magento2 project root folder

[Check this Magento2 module](https://github.com/mundipagg/magento2?files=1)

https://github.com/mundipagg/magento2/blob/master/.phpcs.xml